# Set array with the previous value if it's current value is zero - php

Tags: php, arrays

I want to replace the value '0' in the array values with the previous non-zero number.

The current structure of array is as below:

Could anyone help?

```
Array
(
    [2016-06-16] => -143
    [2016-06-17] => 0
    [2016-06-18] => 0
    [2016-06-19] => 0
    [2016-06-20] => -28
    [2016-06-21] => 517
    [2016-06-22] => 0
    [2016-06-23] => -218
    [2016-06-24] => 0
    [2016-06-25] => 27
    [2016-06-26] => 0
    [2016-06-27] => 0
    [2016-06-28] => 0
    [2016-06-29] => 0
    [2016-06-30] => -798
    [2016-07-01] => 0
    [2016-07-02] => 0
    [2016-07-03] => 0
    [2016-07-04] => 0
    [2016-07-05] => 0
    [2016-07-06] => 0
    [2016-07-07] => 0

)
```

Expected Structure

```
Array
    (
        [2016-06-16] => -143
        [2016-06-17] => -143
        [2016-06-18] => -143
        [2016-06-19] => -143
        [2016-06-20] => -28
        [2016-06-21] => 517
        [2016-06-22] => 517
        [2016-06-23] => -218
        [2016-06-24] => -218
        [2016-06-25] => 27
        [2016-06-26] => 27
        [2016-06-27] => 27
        [2016-06-28] => 27
        [2016-06-29] => 27
        [2016-06-30] => -798
        [2016-07-01] => -798
        [2016-07-02] => -798
        [2016-07-03] => -798
        [2016-07-04] => -798
        [2016-07-05] => -798
        [2016-07-06] => -798
        [2016-07-07] => -798

    )
```

I tried using below code, but it shows error and on changing it changes the first value at the maximum.

```
        foreach ($jsonstatisticsData as $arrdata=> $val)
        {
            if($val==0){

    $prevarray=prev($jsonstatisticsData);
    $prev_value= $prevarray[$arrdata];
    $jsonstatisticsData[$arrdata]=$prev_value;

            }

        }
```

Comment: what should be there, if the first item is 0?

Comment: `array_walk(
    $data,
    function (&$value) {
        static $previous = 0;
        if ($value == 0) {
            $value = $previous;
        }
        $previous = $value;
    }
);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the first can not be `0` then use this:

```
$prev = 0;
foreach ($jsonstatisticsData as $arrdata => $val) {
    if ($val == 0) {
        $jsonstatisticsData[$arrdata] = $prev;
    }
    $prev = $val;
}
```

If the first could be `0` then you should set the `$prev` to something outside of the loop, and first will be that value.

Comment: You will need to add an `else` condition to avoid `$prev` being set back to `0`. You can also pass values by reference to simplify the loop a little - update the lines `foreach ($jsonstatisticsData as &$val) {` and then `$val = $prev;`. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Comment: Yes, Worked with the else condition added. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Back to the basics?

```
<?php

$arr = [23,0,0,56,0,0,0,0,0,12,6,98,0,0];
    $nonzero = 0;
    for($i = 0; $i<count($arr); $i++){
        if($arr[$i]===0){
         $arr[$i] = $nonzero;
        }else{
         $nonzero = $arr[$i];
        }
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using reference `&`, you can make the foreach more simple.

You should try this :

```
    $prev = 0;
    foreach ($jsonstatisticsData as &$val) {
        if ($val == 0) $val = $prev;
        else $prev = $val;
    }
```